# SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer without existing destination table

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is it possible to dump a `System.Data.DataTable` into a SQL Server destination table which doesn't exist yet?  I realize one option would be to create the table manually, but I am importing from a user-input CSV so I have no a-priori knowledge of the columns.

```
        using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(TheConnString, options))
        {
            bc.DestinationTableName = destTableName;
            bc.WriteToServer(theTable);
            // Problem is theTable doesnt exist on database yet!
        }
```

Comment: is `theTable` a `DataTable` or a `IDataReader`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain System.Data.DataTable

Comment: A CSV has no schema with proper data types, max length, and nullability needed to create a proper matching relational table so I guess your data table has only a bunch of string or object columns. You could create a generic table dynamically with varchar(MAX)/nvarchar(MAX) columns but I think it would be better if you add more detail to your question so we can suggest a better solution.

Comment: Why not create a `CREATE TABLE` statement dynamically from the metadata in `theTable.Columns`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that's what I guess I'll have to do; hoping someone had done that already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started creating the table dynamically:

```
    static string GetSqlType(Type dataTableColunmType)
    {
        //per type mappings here 
        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings
        if (dataTableColunmType == typeof(string))
        {
            return "nvarchar(max)";
        }
        else if (dataTableColunmType == typeof(int))
        {
            return "int";
        }
        else if (dataTableColunmType == typeof(Single))
        {
            return "real";
        }
        else if (dataTableColunmType == typeof(double))
        {
            return "float";
        }
        else if (dataTableColunmType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            return "datetime";
        }
        else if (dataTableColunmType == typeof(byte[]))
        {
            return "varbinary(max)";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Type {dataTableColunmType.Name} not supported");
        }


    }
    static string GetCreateTableDDL(string tableName, DataTable table)
    {
        var ddl = new StringBuilder();
        ddl.AppendLine($"create table [{tableName}] (");
        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            ddl.Append($"  [{col.ColumnName}] {GetSqlType(col.DataType)}, ");
        }
        ddl.Length = ddl.Length - ", ".Length;
        ddl.Append(")");

        return ddl.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Quick question - does using `nvarchar(max)` slow the database down?  Would finding the max length on each column `x` and then doing `nvarchar(x)` be more efficient in the long run?

Comment: The difference is small.  If you are designing a real table, use nvarchar(n) and specify a maximum length.  But for something like this nvarchar(max) is fine.